# What XSS attacks could be done with window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser

Which XSS attacks could be done when redirecting with `window.location` and user input data.

I think this ones

- User can write a post with a title that contains `http://` so the end user ends up on a bad site.
- User can write a post with title "`javascript:EvilCode()`" I think this will be executed in some browsers?

Comment: `window.location.href = Post_Title;` does not make any sense, because the post title is not a URL? If the post title is only a part of the URL, you will have to URL encode it anyway

Comment: Hm, maybe a crappy example. But the point is that it could be URL that execute code, or redirect the user to another page.

Comment: What's hard about URL-encoding it? Even PHP and JavaScript have those functions built-in.

Comment: My question is more like what types of XSS hacks could be done.

Comment: All types, as in HTML injection and arbitrary Javascript injection. I don't see the point of the question, though, because *any* type of XSS is deadly for your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are potentially allowing [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) if you don't URL encode the data first.

Comment: I know, what types of XSS do you know? I only could came up with execute evilCode and redirect to another website.

Comment: Have a look at the link, it goes through all the common types of XSS and how to protect against them.